# Hibernate, save id without referencing in the object

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, foreign-keys, hibernate-mapping

Let's say I have an object

```
class User
{
    int id;
    String name;
    String password;
    List<Property> properties;
}
```

And

```
class Property
{
    int id;
    String key;
    String value;
}
```

The table in MySQL however is slightly different.

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45),
  `password` VARCHAR(45),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE `property` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `key` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `value` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `userId` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `userId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`userId`)
    REFERENCES `user` (`userId`));
```

How would I create hibernate annotations so that if I would like to save user object I will end up saving/creating new properties accordingly?

I really do not want to put User object inside Property object for this to happen.

Comment: read about `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToMany`

Comment: @Jens I read about `@OneToMany` which is what I need. But all the examples and explanations I saw, require me to have `User` object inside my `Property` object for saving to work. I would like to not have `User` object inside `Property` object. Is it at all possible?

Comment: You have to read about uni-directional relation ship. what you have seen is the bi-directonal relation ship

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using unidirectional OneToMany mapping, but it will create an extra table with `userId` and `propertyId` column and your property table will not need `userId` column. In this case you will be able to get all properties of user, but you won't be able to query a particular property belongs to which user.

If you want to have user information in a property object, you must use bi-directional OneToMany mapping and for that you will need put user inside Property class.You can control the initialization of User object inside Property class while fetching data from database by configuring fetch type for User. By default, fetch type is LAZY, meaning User object will fetched from database only when you use it.